# apt problems: can't install GParted on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apt, gparted

I'm trying to install GParted on my Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted
```

but I'm getting the following output:

```
 root@adam-desktop:/home/adam# sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libvncserver0 patch
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils kpartx dmraid gpart
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gparted
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1902 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6746 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  gparted
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ oneiric-getdeb/apps gparted amd64 0.12.1-1~getdeb1
  Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/g/gparted/gparted_0.12.1-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ oneiric-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-getdeb_apps_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ oneiric-getdeb/apps i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-getdeb_apps_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Do you suspect what's wrong?

### UPDATE

After I've made:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
```

I'm getting:

```
    root@adam-desktop:/home/adam# sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
root@adam-desktop:/home/adam# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
Ign http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                                                                       
Ign http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease                                                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                                                                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                                                                        
Ign http://www.bunkus.org ./ InRelease                                                                                           
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                                                                               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                                                                                   
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg                                                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg                                                                      
Hit http://www.bunkus.org ./ Release.gpg                                                                                         
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg                                                                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                                                                                 
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release                                                                          
Hit http://www.bunkus.org ./ Release                                                                                             
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release                                                                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                                                                            
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources                                                                      
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources                                                                        
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources                                                                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release                                                                                 
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb InRelease                                                                           
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb Release.gpg                                                                         
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb Release                                                             
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps Sources/DiffIndex                                              
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                       
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                        
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps TranslationIndex                                               
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps Sources                                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages                                                 
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                                                  
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps Translation-en                                                 
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Err http://archive.getdeb.net oneiric-getdeb/apps Translation-pl                                                 
  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main amd64 Packages                                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe amd64 Packages                           
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages                                                
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages                                                  
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages                          
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex                                             
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex                                             
Hit http://www.bunkus.org ./ Sources                                                                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                                                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Sources                                   
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex                         
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Sources                                                    
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Sources                                              
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Sources                                                
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Sources                                              
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main amd64 Packages                                             
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                         
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages                                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages                                              
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                        
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages                                          
Hit http://www.bunkus.org ./ Packages                                                      
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex                                           
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main amd64 Packages                                                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                                                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Sources                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources                                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Sources                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe amd64 Packages                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner amd64 Packages                                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages                                                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner TranslationIndex                                                
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Sources                                            
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Sources                                                  
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Sources                                            
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Sources                                              
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main amd64 Packages                                           
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                      
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages                                            
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe TranslationIndex                                        
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages                                        
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                   
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                   
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-pl                                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-pl                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-pl                                               
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en                                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en                  
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-pl                           
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en                                         
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Translation-en                                           
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en                                     
Hit http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en                                          
Ign http://www.bunkus.org ./ Translation-en                                                
Ign http://www.bunkus.org ./ Translation-pl                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-pl
Ign http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-pl
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/apps/source/Sources  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/apps/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-getdeb/apps/i18n/Translation-pl  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@adam-desktop:/home/adam#
```

Comment: This is because 11.04 reached end of life last month and is no longer supported.  You need to upgrade.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the sources.list by your saved sources.list. You need to remove the files from folder: `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: Take a look on update. It didn't helped too much.

Comment: Remove getdeb.net from sources.list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the sources.list file with following command `sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Probably getdeb.net is down, choose an other repository in /etc/apt/sources.list.